# Extract single unicode character from string

Tags: string, unicode, character-encoding, fortran

The problem begins when I stumble upon unicode characters. For example, árbol. Right now I handle this by asking if the character at position `i`, that is, `string (i:i)` is less than 127. That means that it belongs to the ASCII table, with this I know for sure that`string (i:i)` is a ***complete single character***. In the other case `(>= 127)` and for my example 'árbol', `string (1,2)` is the ***complete character***.

I think the way I'm handling the strings solves the problem for my practical purposes (handling files in spanish, polish and russian), but in the case of handling chinese letter where characters may take up to 4 bytes then I would have problems.

Is there a way in fortran to single out unicode characters inside a string?

Comment: Does your Fortran processor support the ISO 10646 (i.e. UCS-4) character kind?  If it does, and you use that character kind, then referencing a single character is a trivial operation.

Comment: let's say it does support, how do I reference a single character. Does it have to do with using the module ISO_FORTRAN_ENV

Comment: `string(i:i)`  (I did say it was trivial!)  With the ISO 10646 character kind, each character in the string represents a unicode code point.  The value to use for the character kind for ISO 10646 can be obtained using the `SELECTED_CHAR_KIND` intrinsic.

Comment: You did say it was trivial but I still can't manage to make my string represent a while code point with string(i:i), even though I'm using:
`integer, parameter    :: ucs4 = selected_char_kind ('ISO_10646')`
`character (kind = ucs4, len = 20)  :: string`

Comment: With the case árbol I now get, using string(1:1), a 'Ã'. @IanH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gfortran` does not currently support non-ASCII characters in UTF-8 encoded files, see [here](https://github.com/jacobwilliams/json-fortran/wiki/Unicode-How-To). You can find the corresponding [bug report here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45179).

As a work-around, you can specify the unicode char in Hex-notation: `char(int(z'00E1'), ucs4)`, or `'\u00E1'`. The latter requires the compile option `-fbackslash` to enable the evaluation of the backslash.

```
program character_kind
  use iso_fortran_env
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: ucs4  = selected_char_kind ('ISO_10646')

  character(kind=ucs4,  len=20) :: string

!  string = ucs4_'árbol' ! This does not work
!  string = char(int(z'00E1'), ucs4) // ucs4_'rbol' ! This works
  string = ucs4_'\u00E1rbol' ! This is also working

  open (output_unit, encoding='UTF-8')

  print *, string(1:1)
  print *, string

end program character_kind
```

`ifort` seems not to support `ISO_10646` at all, `selected_char_kind ('ISO_10646')` returns `-1`. With `ifort` 15.0.0 I get the same message as described [here](https://software.intel.com/de-de/forums/topic/327174).